# Writing Complex Numbers in Standard Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Can someone show me how to write complex numbers in standard form?  I missed a few days of class and do not have the text book. Answering a simple question like the one below would help

Write the complex number in standard form.
$6 + \sqrt{−16}$

Comment: I hope that you get the textbook soon.

Comment: Have you tried talking to your teacher, or your fellow students? Those should be your first recourses when making up missed classes.

Comment: All, this OP also posted [this earlier version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151017/11619), In the same vein. Back in the day this question escaped closure. Nowadays it wouldn't stand a chance. I don't understand the votes to reopen at all???

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, one of the votes to reopen is explained in one of the answers here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/downvote-close-delete

Answer (score 6):

$\sqrt{-1}$ is written as just $i$ for "imaginary".

$\sqrt{-x}$ can be factored as $\sqrt{-1\vphantom{x}}\sqrt{x} = i\sqrt{x}$.

"Standard form" for complex numbers is $a + bi$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.  If $a$ or $b$ is 0, you omit that part. For example, you write $3 + 0i$ as just $3$, and $0 + 3i$ as just $3i$.

For your example, you have $6+\sqrt{-16} = 6 + i\sqrt{16} = 6 + 4i$. The "standard form" is $6+4i$.

Comment: You have to be carefull, when defining the imaginary unit as you did, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#Proper_use - the correct way is, to say that \(i\) is defined by \(i^2 = -1\), which is note the same as your definition (to be precise, the root is not defined for complex numbers).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $i^2=-1$, so $\sqrt{-16}=\sqrt{i^216}=i4. $ Hence
 $6+\sqrt {-16}=6+i4{}$

Comment: Who voted this down? Can you explain why?

Comment: I voted it down because the OP's teacher is likely to reject "$6+i4$" as a "standard form" for complex numbers.

Comment: @MarkDominus. So what is the standard form? $6+4i$?

Comment: @Mark: $a+ib$ and $a+bi$ are both explicitly mentioned as standard form in some textbooks, and regardless I don't think that a teacher would be reasonable to not accept $6+i4$ as standard form.

Comment: @MarkDominus. $4i$ or $i4$ does not make any difference. You dont vote down when you dont know. You should find out before you vote down.

Comment: My apologies. ${}$

Comment: $a+ib$ is fine. $6+i4$ is bizarre.

Comment: A pedantic (at this level, at least) note: square roots can do funny things with $i$. For example, the square root of $i^4 = 1$ is $1$, right? And yet it also seems reasonable to write $\sqrt{i^4} = \sqrt{(i^2)^2} = i^2 = -1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. It is not bizarre provided you know what it means. The reason why some textbooks prefer this style is that in case of squre roots the meaning can be misleading. For example $i\sqrt{3}$ might be preferred over $\sqrt{3}i$. This is because the latter appears as if one is finding the square root of the product of $3$ and $i$.

Comment: $i\sqrt3$ is fine. $i4$ is bizarre. It looks like someone meant $i_4$ but couldn't find the underscore key.